# Improving query speed by removing sub queries

Tags: sql, performance, sqlperformance

I'm looking to speed up this query. At the moment it takes just over 20 seconds to execute which is terrible.

I can't find a way to remove the sub queries by using and JOIN functions.

**SQL:**

```
(

    SELECT
        `manual`.`id`,
        `fname`,
        `lname`,
        `email`,
        '' AS `company`,
        '' AS `level`,
        `completed_tests`.`assessment`,
        '' AS `st_ref`,
        '1' AS `manual`,
        `completed_tests`.`percentage`,
        '' AS `last_visit`,
        '' AS `joined`

    FROM
        `manual`

    LEFT JOIN `used_codes` ON `manual`.`id` = `used_codes`.`user` AND `used_codes`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `used_codes` WHERE `user` = `manual`.`id` AND `manual` = 1)
    LEFT JOIN `vcode` ON `manual`.`vcode` = `vcode`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `vcode`.`group` = `groups`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `completed_tests` ON `manual`.`id` = `completed_tests`.`user` AND `completed_tests`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `completed_tests` WHERE `user` = `manual`.`id` AND `manual` = 1)

)
UNION ALL
(

    SELECT
        `users`.`id`,
        `fname`,
        `lname`,
        `email`,
        `company`,
        `users`.`level`,
        `completed_tests`.`assessment`,
        `orders`.`st_ref`,
        '0' AS `manual`,
        `completed_tests`.`percentage`,
        `last_visit`,
        `joined`

    FROM
        `users`

    LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user` AND `orders`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `orders` WHERE `status` = 3 AND `user` = `users`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `used_codes` ON `users`.`id` = `used_codes`.`user` AND `used_codes`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `used_codes` WHERE `user` = `users`.`id` AND `manual` = 1)
    LEFT JOIN `vcode` ON `used_codes`.`vcode` = `vcode`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `vcode`.`group` = `groups`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `completed_tests` ON `users`.`id` = `completed_tests`.`user` AND `completed_tests`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `completed_tests` WHERE `user` = `users`.`id` AND `manual` = 0)

)

ORDER BY `lname` ASC, `fname` ASC;
```

To give you an idea of the database structure, there are two main tables, one for `users` and another for `manual`.  The other tables hold additional data and are linked with the users's ID and another field called `manual` to see which database they belong in.

The problem I'm having is that I need the data of that user to show whether they have any additional data in the other tables or not.  When I tested this using JOIN functions, the record would be removed from the results completely.

I think the main part of the query that need rewriting is the `LEFT JOIN`s.  I can't work out a way that does the same as this: `LEFT JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user AND orders.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM orders WHERE status = 3 AND user = users.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you take out the sub queries like:

`SELECT MAX(id) FROM orders WHERE status = 3 AND user = users.id`

Put them into temp tables and index the id. You can definitely index temp tables and I've seen it make a huge difference in performance when I'm trying to optimize sub queries.

Of course you'll have to remove the user = user.id part, but you can keep the status = 3 part.

You pay the price once for a big query (storing all users with that status and indexing the temp table), but then all subsequent calls are very fast.

Comment: It would be quite a task to do that (where the original code is).  I was thinking of making a cron that would take care of the entire query, as well as additional queries that change and check variables within the results while loop (after the results have been retrieved). So I'm guessing there isn't a way to change this query (alone) to improve its performance?

Comment: The temp table would be in the query above, not a physical table. create table #tmp ( userId int ) etc. You can create an in memory temp table in SQL, index it and then delete it at the end of the query.